# Count the number of duplicates in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an application inserting a numbered sequence of logs into elasticsearch.
Under certain conditions, after stopping my application, I find that in elasticsearch there are more logs than I have actually generated.
This simple aggregation helped me find out that a few duplicates are present:

```
curl /logstash-*/_search?pretty -d '{
    size: 0,
    aggs: {
        msgnum_terms: {
            terms: {
                field: "msgnum.raw",
                min_doc_count: 2,
                size: 0
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

`msgnum` is the field containing the numeric sequence. Normally it should be unique and the resulting `doc_count`s never exceed 1. Instead I get something like:

```
{
  "took" : 33,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 100683,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "msgnum_terms" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "4097",
        "doc_count" : 2
      }, {
        "key" : "4099",
        "doc_count" : 2
      ...
      ...
      ...
      }, {
        "key" : "5704",
        "doc_count" : 2
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I count the exact number of duplicates in order to make sure that they are the only cause of mismatch between number of generated log lines and number of hits in elasticsearch?

Comment: You can use the group by query to get the duplicate records. Also, you can convert your SQL query int the elastic search query. Refer the following link for group by query and SQL query conversion-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56751060/how-to-include-group-clause-in-count-api-of-elasticsearch/56752801#56752801